# Is it possible to buy a SIM card in a transit zone of Doha airport?

Tags: transit, cellphones, doha

I am traveling to the UK with a transit flight that stops in Doha (Qatar capital) and I need to buy a SIM card in the transit zone of the airport.

Comment: Will you pass Qatar immigration and enter Qatar, or will your next flight take you to another country?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response I have to wait 5 hour in airport for the a flight to london

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The [Doha Airport's official webpage](https://dohahamadairport.com) contains a link to a [page of maps of the various terminals and concourses](https://dohahamadairport.com/airport-guide/at-the-airport/maps).

The maps for Transit Concourses A, B, D, and E show various facilities (seating, restrooms, customs/immigration desks, etc.) but do not show any shops or stores in these areas.

There is no map for a Transit Concourse C, which may or may not exist. I've never been this airport.

Comment: This… doesn't seem right. Presumably by "the transit zone", OP means "the area of the airport in which i can hang out in between my flights", not "the place i have to go through security." There are, as you'd expect for any large airport nowadays and as confirmed by the Doha Airport website, [plenty of shops](https://dohahamadairport.com/shop) in the departures area, though I can't figure out how to answer the original question if any of them sells SIM cards.

Comment: @mlc The OP asked about purchases within the "transit zone" of the airport. While the word "transit" can have a broad meaning, this question suggests a "transit without entry," where the traveler arrives and does not pass that country's immigration control. Instead, they remain in a transit space in the airport, from which they later depart for another country. The Doha airport maps cover various concourses, some of which are specifically noted as "Transit Concourses." Those concourses don't show shops or stores. I think the answer is correct.

Comment: I posted a comment under the question; perhaps the OP will clarify the itinerary.

Comment: I would be extremely surprised if you were correct and transiting passengers were not allowed to access the shops etc in the "departure concourses" in Doha, presumably after undergoing some sort of non-immigration security check in the "transit concourses".

Comment: I disagree. After a passenger arrives at the airport, checks in for a departing flight and passes security, the passenger is in a "departure concourse." The passenger may change his mind about flying, and exit to landside without passing immigration and customs. Because transit passengers have not passed immigration and customs, they will not be permitted into a "departure concourse" and they will not be able to exit to landside. That's the narrow interpretation of the OP's "transit zone," and what I think the OP is referring to. Perhaps the OP will report his experience as an answer.

Comment: If it needs confirmation, which is incredible, I can confirm absolutely that (obviously) when you transit Doha, there is access to many shops.  I don't remember if there's in particular a "SIM shop", nor do I know if it's legal to buy SIMs withotu local ID etc in that country.